# Datatables cell value updating only when refresh the page

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have star rating in last column through java script,

1. When i update my rating through on click its updating in database but not in data table.
2. Because of this ,i am not able search or sort in last column with updated data.

I need to get updated data in data tables  when api calls for updating start 
Any solution? Here is code: http://debug.datatables.net/uyidet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 performanceRatingStar();   
  
      $.ajaxSetup({
       async : false
      });
      
      $('#table_id2').DataTable({
       "order" : [ [ 2, "asc" ] ],
       "aoColumnDefs" : [ {
        "bSortable" : false,
        "aTargets" : [2]
       } ],
       "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
                 var api = this.api();
                 var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
                 var last=null;
      
                 api.column(2, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
                     if ( last !== group ) {                      
                         $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                             '<tr class="group" style="background-color: #ddd !important"><td colspan="15">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                         );
      
                         last = group;
                     }
                 } );
       }
      });
      // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
      $('#table_id2 tfoot th')
        .each(
          function() {
           var title = $('#table_id2 thead th')
             .eq($(this).index()).text();
           if (title == 'First'
               || title == 'Last'  
               || title=='GroupName'
               || title == 'Position'
               || title == 'Market'
            || title == 'Performance Rating'
             ){

            $(this)
              .html(
                '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />');
           }

          });

      // DataTable
      var table = $('#table_id2').DataTable();

      // Apply the search
      table.columns().eq(0).each(function(colIdx) {
           $('input',table.column(colIdx).footer()).on(
               'keyup',function() { 
                table.column(colIdx).search(this.value).draw();
               });
          });

      // Order by the grouping
         $('#table_id2').on( 'click', 'tr.group', function () {
             var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
             if ( currentOrder[0] === 2 && currentOrder[1] === 'asc' ) {
                 table.order( [ 2, 'desc' ] ).draw();
             }
             else {
                 table.order( [ 2, 'asc' ] ).draw();
             }
         } );

});

function performanceRatingStar(){
   $(".rateYo").each(function(e)
      {
      var rateYoDivId = this.id;
      var rosterId_userId_fields = rateYoDivId.split(/_/);
      var rosterId = rosterId_userId_fields[0];
   var replaceRosterId = rosterId.replace("rateYo", ""); 
   var userId = rosterId_userId_fields[1];
   var rateFromHiddenField = $('#hiddenRating'+replaceRosterId+"_"+userId).val(); 
   var  pubId = $(this).attr('data-showPubPosiId');
   var   uId = $(this).attr('data-userId');

   $(this).rateYo({
         onSet: function(rating, rateYoInstance)
      { 
          getRate = rateFromHiddenField;
      },
      
          onChange: function (rating, rateYoInstance) {
          
       if(rating == 0){
       $(this).next().text("Not Rated")
    }else if (rating == 1){
    $(this).next().text("Poor Performance");
    }else if (rating == 2){
    $(this).next().text("Needs Improvement");
    }else if (rating == 3){
    $(this).next().text("Solid Performance");
    }else if (rating == 4){
    $(this).next().text("Exceeded Expectations");
    }else if (rating == 5){
    $(this).next().text("Best In Class");
    }
    },
       starWidth: "20px",
       numStars: 5,
       fullStar: true
       });
       
    if(getRate == 0){
    $("#ratingStatus"+replaceRosterId).text("Not Rated")
    }else if (getRate == 1){
    $("#ratingStatus"+replaceRosterId).text("Poor Performance");
    }else if (getRate == 2){
    $("#ratingStatus"+replaceRosterId).text("Needs Improvement");
    }else if (getRate == 3){
    $("#ratingStatus"+replaceRosterId).text("Solid Performance");
    }else if (getRate == 4){
    $("#ratingStatus"+replaceRosterId).text("Exceeded Expectations");
    }else if (getRate == 5){
    $("#ratingStatus"+replaceRosterId).text("Best In Class");
    }
   
    $("#"+rateYoDivId).rateYo("rating", rateFromHiddenField);
     $("#"+rateYoDivId ).mouseover(function() {
    var maxValue = $("#"+rateYoDivId).rateYo("option", "rating");
    });
      });
 
  $(".rateYo").rateYo().on("rateyo.set", function (e, data)
    {
   var  pubId1 = $(this).attr('data-showPubPosiId');
   var   uId1 = $(this).attr('data-userId');
   $.ajax({
     url : "api/users/saveOrUpdateRating/"+data.rating+"/"+pubId1+"/"+uId1,
     contentType : "application/json",
     success : function(response) 
     {
     count++; 
     }
     }); 
  });
}
```

```html
<table class=" " id="table_id2">
         <thead>
          <tr>
           <th class="">First</th>
           <th>Last</th>
           <th>Position</th>
           <th>Market</th>
           <th>Performance Rating</th>

          </tr>
         </thead>
         <tfoot>
          <tr>
           <th class="">First</th>
           <th>Last</th>
           <th>Position</th>
           <th>Market</th>
           <th>Performance Rating</th>
                                      </tr>
         </tfoot>
         <tbody>
         
             
<span th:text="|${roster.firstName}|"></span>
                       </td>
<td th:text="${roster.lastName}" class="lastName"
            th:attr="id='fnameId'+${roster.lastName}"></td>

<span style="float: right">Supervisor : 
 <span th:text="${roster.supervisorName}"></span></span></td>

<td th:text="${roster.positions}" class="positions"
            th:attr="id='fnameId'+${roster.positions}"></td>
<td  class="state"            th:attr="id='fnameId'+${roster.state}"><span th:text="${roster.stateCode}"></span></td>
<td class="initialRating"><input type="hidden"      th:attr="id='hiddenRating'+${roster.showPubPosiId}+'_'+${roster.userId},data-showPubPosiId=${roster.showPubPosiId},data-userId=${roster.userId}" onclick="ratingData(this)" th:value="${roster.perforRating}" />
  <a href="#!"  class="rateYo" th:attr="id='rateYo'+${roster.showPubPosiId}+'_'+${roster.userId},data-showPubPosiId=${roster.showPubPosiId},data-userId=${roster.userId}"
            style="width: 120px; float: left;" />
<div style="color: #666; float: left; margin-left: 7px; margin-top: 3px; width: 150px;"
             th:attr="id='ratingStatus'+${roster.showPubPosiId}"></div>
            <div th:attr="id='ratingOnChange'+${roster.showPubPosiId}"></div></td>
           
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You might want to format your code snippets and reduce/correct intendation for better readability.

Comment: Btw, this seems to be related to JavaScript only. Where's the connection to Java?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to update the column with this statement:

```js
$(this).next().text("Not Rated");
```

To update the data so that the DataTables plugin will know it has changed, you have to use its [`cell().data()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29.data%28%29) function, then do a [`draw()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) for this to show on the browser.

I would also strongly recommend applying a variable to the dataTable to making working with it easier:

```js
var myDataTable = $('#table_id2').DataTable({ /* ... skipped ... */ });

myDataTable.cell($(this).next()).data("Not Rated").draw();
```